# Wifi switch Amber (off) no matter what I do: Centos(RPM based Linux) w/ BCM4311 as wlan0

Tags: wireless, networking, broadcom

The wifi switch  is permanently off in my hp dv6604nr in my Linux partition.

This laptop is peculiar- wifi remains OFF by default until after windows 7
boots. Then it turns on after OS is loaded. BIOS has no options to keep
wi-fi on.

Its a BCM4311 WLAN card .
From what is known 3 methods exist to turn it on / enable wlan
-- Use Broadcoms native stack : has some limitations including absensce of monitor mode
-- Use NDISWRAPPER : last choice
-- B43 drivers

I choose # 3. I followed this to a T
sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware/ wl_apsta_mimo.o
after downloading broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5.tar.bz2\
sudo rmmod b43

modprobe b43

earlier the WLAN card was not listed now I can see it

```
 rfkill unblock all
[admin@localhost ~]$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
iwconfig wlan0
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any 
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
more cat /etc/modprobe.d/*...
/* last line .No blacklisted brm exists */
options b43 nohwcrypt=1 qos=0
```

I am still stuck - I cant get the WLAN to turn on . Its ALWAYS Amber instead of Blue , toggling the switching L-R - no effect.
PL tell me how to get Wi-fi working using B43 drivers and keep turned on the WLAN switch like in my windows 7 partition

Comment: Did you up your interface with `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official page for getting wifi working on that model laptop: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HP_Pavillion_dv6000_%28dv6604nr%29